# Simple "if" branch in one line

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
if b > 5:
    a += 1
elif b < 0:
    a += 2
else:
    a += 3
```

In C there is a convenient (although not very transparent) way to write it in one line:

```
b > 5 ? a+=1 : b < 0 ? a+=2 : a+=3;
```

Is there a way to write it that concisely in Python?

Comment: The concise way would be to write it as a full if statement. I would hate to have to read a nested conditional.

Comment: based on "The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters", "Simple is better than complex.". read it by `import this` in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is, but it's not all that much shorter and loses on readability:

`a += 1 if b>5 else 2 if b<0 else 3`

Comment: Suggestion for a bit more readability: `1 if b>5 else (2 if b<0 else 3)`.